# Limit $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}$

Tags: limits

- List item

$$\lim_{x \to \dfrac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{\sin x-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}}$$ What I did is set x to be: $$x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+h,h \to 0$$ So I got:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\cos h+\sin h-1)}{h}$$ But I have no idea what to do next. Please help...

Comment: You could have obtained the result directly by observing that $\;\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}4\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and applying the definition of derivative...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni How do I differentiate the limit when I get $$\lim_{x \to \dfrac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{\sin x-sin \dfrac{\pi}{4}}{x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}}$$

Comment: The limit itself is the derivative : $$\lim_{x \to \dfrac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{f(x)-f\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)}{x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}}=?$$

Comment: @RaymondManzoni $$\lim_{x \to \dfrac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{x^2-(\dfrac{\pi}{4})^2}{x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}}$$???

Comment: Apply $\displaystyle f'(a)=\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\;$ to $f(x)=x^2$ or simplify first to $x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ before taking the limit.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I haven't learned derivatives yet, please explain me this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11124/discussion-between-a6tech-and-raymond-manzoni)

Comment: Btw to finish it your way do :
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\sin h+\cos h-1)}{h}&=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\sin h+O(h^2))}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\sin h}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align}
Since $\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sin h}{h}=1$. ($O(h^2)$ means that the terms are of order $h^2$ while $\sin(h)=O(h)$ for $h\to 0$)

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{1-\cos 2u}u=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{2\sin^2u}u=2\left(\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u}u\right)^2\left(\lim_{u\to0}u\right)$$

and we know $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u}u=1$

---

Alternatively, using $\displaystyle\sin C-\sin D=2\sin\frac{C-D}2\cos\frac{C-D}2$

$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{\sin x-\sin\frac\pi4}{x-\frac\pi4}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{2\sin\frac{x-\frac\pi4}2\cos\frac{x+\frac\pi4}2}{x-\frac\pi4}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{\sin\frac{x-\frac\pi4}2}{\frac{x-\frac\pi4}2}\left(\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4} \cos\frac{x+\frac\pi4}2\right)$$

$$=\cdots$$

Comment: @DanielR, rectified & added another method